# Javascript "mouseover" and "mouseout" events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, jquery-events, mouseout

Consider [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce6PK/):

HTML:

```
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='b'></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #777;
}
.b {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
        switch (e.type) {
            case 'mouseover': {
                $('.b').offset({'left': $(this).offset().left,
                                'top': $(this).offset().top})
                       .width($(this).outerWidth())
                       .height($(this).outerHeight())
                       .show();
                break;
            }       
            case 'mouseout': {
                $('.b').hide();
                break;
            }        
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce6PK/), some kind of flickering occurs, because when `.b` is shown, `mouseout` automatically occurs. How would you solve this problem ?

The desired behavior is: when the mouse is over `.a`, `.b` should be shown (should cover `.a`), and when the mouse is not over `.a`, `.b` should not be shown. `.a` should always be shown.

The position and dimensions of `.a` is not constant (should be calculated on the fly).

Comment: Should `.b` *cover* `.a` initially?

Comment: No. Only when the mouse becomes over `.a`.

Comment: You could try making `.b` a child of `.a`, although sometimes that may not be desirable

Comment: have you tried adding a few millisecond timer so that it can fire a mouse over event and keep it showing?

Comment: I don't like the idea of timeout. I'm looking for cleaner solution.

Comment: Why do you set the values in the mouseover handler?  You could put the left, top, width and height attributes in the CSS for b couldn't you?

Comment: I don't understand how. Could you show the code please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I come up with [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce6PK/1/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.a').live('mouseover', function(e) {
        $('.b').offset({'left': $(this).offset().left,
                        'top': $(this).offset().top})
               .width($(this).outerWidth())
               .height($(this).outerHeight())
               .show();
    });
    $('.b').live('mouseout', function(e) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: change `$('.b').offset` to `$('.b').css` when setting position. otherwise this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $('.a').live('mouseover', function(e) {
        $('.b').offset({'left': $(this).offset().left,
                        'top': $(this).offset().top})
                .width($(this).outerWidth())
                .height($(this).outerHeight())
                .show();
    });
    $('.b').live('mouseout', function(e) {
        $('.b').hide();
        break;
    });
});
```

This should mean that when the user moves thier mouse over area a, area b is shown and then when they move thier mouse out of area b, area a is reshown.

Comment: This is exactly the solution that I came up with :) But not, I think it is not good enough, because the dimensions of `.b` can be different from those of `.a`. Do you have any other idea ?